# Gradle: How to execute task after create lib.aar file?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have gradle task which unbacks lib-debug.aar
need execute this task after crate this lib-debug.aar file

```
task unzip<<{
    copy {
        def aarFile = file("${buildDir}/outputs/aar/lib-debug.aar")
        def outputDir = file("${buildDir}/outputs/eclipse")
        from zipTree(aarFile)
        into outputDir
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
unzip.dependsOn assemble
```

That will make it so that whenever you run the unzip task, the assemble task has to have run before.